# Prove $\lim_{ (x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Can some one prove the limit using epsilon delta method to prove that the limit exists
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}=0
$$

Comment: HINT $\left|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le 1$.

Comment: try polar coordinates

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

We have $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac {r^3\cos^3\theta-r^3\sin^3\theta}{r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta} \\=\lim_{r \to 0} \frac {r^3\cos^3\theta-r^3\sin^3\theta}{r^2} =\lim_{r \to 0} r(\cos^3\theta-\sin^3\theta).$$

Can you complete?

Comment: ``\sin`` and ``\cos`` are proper $\LaTeX$ commands, for your note.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x, y)  \not = (0, 0);$

$\dfrac{|xx ^2-yy^2¦}{x^2+y^2}| \le\dfrac{|x|x^2+|y|y^2}{x^2+y^2}\le|x|+|y|\le 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$

$\delta =? $

P. S. Tito' s comment.